# Can't hide dark line under nav bar - setBackgroundImage/shadow not working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

[image]

There is a fine dark line between the navigation bar and the segmented control shown above. I need to try and remove this line.

The navigation bar is not translucent (and I don't want it to be).

I have tried this code but it's not working:

```
@IBOutlet var navBar: UINavigationBar!

self.navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

I have tried the solutions in linked answers and they do not work. This question has the same problem but the answers are the same and they don't work.

Comment: Why did you delete and repost the same question?

Comment: Are you sure you are referring to the same navigation bar? I.e. `self.navigationController.navigationBar` instead of `self.navBar`?

Comment: @rmaddy Because you wrongly marked the question as a duplicate meaning all potential answers had ran off and no one was viewing it anymore.

Comment: @LeoNatan After some digging, I found that wrapping the UINavigationBar in a Navigation Controller and then using your code worked. The reason the line wasn't going was because the navigation bar wasn't wrapped in a Nav Controller.

Comment: What do you mean wrap? If you are using a navigation controller, you need to modify that. If you are adding a bar directly in code or interface builder, you need to edit the bar directly. Another option is to use appearance proxy to modify all bars.

Comment: @LeoNatan I mean embed. I tried directly editing the bar on its own with the code above and it didn't work. Embedding in the Navigation Controller and using `self.navigationController.navigationBar` instead worked. Not sure why, but it's working nicely now

Comment: Please add an answer and mark as accepted.

Comment: @user3605739 FYI - I reopened your previous question less than 5 minutes after closing it. There was no need to delete and repost.

Answer (score 3):

Within **AppDelegate**, this has globally changed the format of the NavBar and removes the bottom line/border for **Swift** lovers:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : (UIFont(name: "FONT NAME", size: 18))!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()] }
```

Haven't managed to implement anything different on a specific VC, but this will help 90% of people.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple solution to hide the line would be

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
}
```